# How to make a Firebase Cloud function with full read/write admin powers on storage?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have created some functions that upload and download files from firebase storage with cloud functions using the Firebase SDK and they work.
I would like for the functions to be executed as admin so that they don't need to abide by the storage rules.

I have replaced the firebase SDK with the admin SDK but I found out that my firebase.storage().ref reference doesn't work anymore and by reading around some docs I have realized I now need to use the google cloud services system instead.

So my question is, is there a way to have a cloud function have administrator powers on the entire firebase project without having to switch to google cloud functions and if not, is there a work around to do that so that I can somehow authorize my cloud function to have full read/write powers on the entire storage? I am puzzled!

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');

const functions = require('firebase-functions');

require("firebase-admin")
require("firebase")
require("firebase/storage");

var serviceAccount = require("serviceAccount.json");

var config = {
    [...]
    credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  var storage = firebase.storage();
  var storageRef = storage.ref(); //This returns .ref() is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase client libraries are not intended to work on backend server environments.  The Firebase Admin SDK is meant for backends, but the API to access Cloud Storage is different than the client SDK.  The Admin SDK  just [wraps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.storage) the Cloud Storage server SDKs.  So for node environments, you are actually just going to use the [Cloud Storage Node.js client](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/).

When you call:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const storage = admin.storage()
```

you are getting a [Storage](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/Storage) object from the node SDK.  It doesn't have a ref() method.  You will need to get a [Bucket](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/Bucket) object and use that instead:

```
const bucket = storage.bucket()
```

From here, you should continue to use the API docs I'm linking to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Am I using an entirely different service here? I have read that the pricings actually change for Google Cloud Storage and also the Authentication method is different. Would that be a problem?

Comment: Just to make sure, is there actually no way of knowing if a database request comes from a cloud function or not while using the Firebase SDK? Could I manually authenticate the user with the Firebase Authentication SDK to workaround this issue?

Comment: That sounds like a completely different issue than the one you first posted about.  Could you post a new question?  The admin SDK / Cloud SDK uses the full permissions granted to the service account that you used to initialize it.  That's really all you need to know about having full control over your storage bucket.

Comment: I will post a new question once the cooldown expires. All I want to do is make sure that my cloud function has permission to store and retrieve data from the storage without being authenticated, in the simplest way possible (it'd be preferable if I could still use the Firebase SDK API). Thanks for the help

Comment: The server SDKs have nothing to do with Firebase Authentication or the end user.

Comment: I apologize, but I am new to Firebase and programming in general. I just simply want to make any cloud function be able to operate on the firebase storage and right now that doesn't happen because my rules are set to authenticated users only. So my question is, is there any way to workaround this issue by simply changing the firebase rules instead of using the AdminSDK?

Comment: The server SDKs always bypass all security rules all the time.

Comment: The setup I am currently using for Firebase Storage is this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files and I am putting that code on a cloud function and it doesn't work with authenticated users only rules

Comment: As I said up front, the Firebase client SDKs are not meant for use in backend environments.  The documentation you're referring to is for web clients, not backends.  You want to use the Admin SDK for that instead, which is what my answer is trying to tell you.